# How to get a random embedding, from an embedding matrix in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, word-embedding

Assume that I have created an embedding matrix for some words in my training set, like below:

```
with train_graph.as_default():
    word_embedding = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform((n_vocab, 256), 0, 1), name='word_embedding')
```

I can use `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_embedding, inputs)` to get the embeddings for the words that are in a specific batch, during training. But how can I get a random embedding and use it in, let us say, a `matmul` operation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using eager execution:

```
# Create the variable
x = tfe.Variable(tf.ones([10, 20]))
# Get random integer in [0, 20)
y = tf.random_uniform(shape=(), maxval=20, dtype=tf.int32)
# Get the y'th row from x.
z = tf.gather(x, y, axis=1)
```

For regular TensorFlow, just replace variable creation.